# $.ajax call for Kohana 3.2 controller returns 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, kohana-3, php

Using Kohana 3.2, JQuery 1.4.4, Firefox browser, 
Trying to get a $.ajax call to work but it's returning always 404 error

here is my configuration
my URL I'm using is 127.0.0.1/xyz/kdi

my URL::base() is xyz/kdi  -> executes Reports/welcome.php index action

my Bootstrap Route:

```
Route::set('default', '(<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'reports',
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

controllers:
 1. controller/reports/welcome.php
 2. controller/reports/xml.php

views:
 1. views/reports/mainReport.php (called by welcome.php)
 2. views/reports/xml.php

putting the following Request to controller xml in mainReport.php works great.

```
<?php echo Request::factory('reports/xml/index/77')->execute(); ?>
```

Here is the $.ajax call I am using in the View:

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: '<?php URL::base()?>reports/xml',  // <--- this is the problematic line
cache: false,
dataType:'json',
data:{params:param},
success: function(resultArray, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
    alert('success');
    }
});
```

my XML controller looks like this

```
class Controller_Reports_Xml extends Controller_BlankLayout {
    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response){
        parent::__construct($request, $response);
    }
    public function action_index(){
        if ($this->request->is_ajax()) {
            $params = json_decode($_POST['params']);
            echo Debug::vars($params);
            //echo 1/0;
            $this->auto_render = FALSE;
            }else{
                $id = $this->request->param('id');
                $this->template->content = 'success to receive the param '.$id;
            }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting 404, searching everywhere on the web shows that the ajax call is correct, which makes me think it's related to Kohana configurations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do by `echo 1/0;`? Raise a fatal error?

Comment: it's for debugging, not really part of the code.  I just commented it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php URL::base()?>reports/xml
```

This is likely returning http://www.yoursite.comreports/xml aka, 404.

Change it to:

```
<?php URL::base()?>/reports/xml
```

Comment: doing this I get http://127.0.0.1/reports/xml  404       with my original code I get    http://127.0.0.1/xyz/kdi/reports/xml  404,, any ideas??